# Python: How to integrate an initial value problem backwards AND forwards in time, using initialscipy.integrate.solve_ivp?

Tags: python, scipy

I am using solve_ivp from scipy.integrate to solve an initial value problem `y'(t) = fun(t,y)` with `y(t0)=y0`. The help is [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.solve_ivp.html), from which one can see that the most basic call of the function is of the form:

```
solve_ivp(fun,[t0,tf],y0)
```

As stated, here `y0=y(t0)`. I already figured out, that one can integrate backwards in time by entering a `tf` which is smaller than `t0`. However I don't know how I can integrate both, backwards and forwards in time in one go.

I.e., I want to integrate over an interval `[ti,tf]`, where `ti<t0<tf` and where still `y0=y(t0)` as before. Is that possible? Or do I have to solve twice, and then piece the solutions together afterwards?

Thanks for suggestions!

Comment: Check out the documentation for the `t_span` argument -- this is a one-sided integration.  To get a two sided result (i.e. where the initial condition is not an endpoint) two calls will be needed.

Comment: @AbbeGijly That's what I thought. Just wanted to make sure I am not missing something, and unnecessarily complicating things. Thanks for the answer!